# Localhost Drupal Install on Linux shows file and not site

Tags: drush, composer

I am trying to set up a local Drupal install on my Linux 16.04 laptop install for learning/exploring Drupal.

I have made it through [this install guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/linux-development-environments/set-up-a-local-development-drupal)
, completing all steps, but when launching my `http://my_example_drupal_site.localhost/web/`
I am getting the below output.

Any idea why this is?

```
/**
 * @file
 * The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
 *
 * All Drupal code is released under the GNU General Public License.
 * See COPYRIGHT.txt and LICENSE.txt files in the "core" directory.
 */

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

---

**Solved**

Followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) as suggested and got my install working.

Ran into two issues along the way. Turns out when setting up my Linux Box long ago, I had an entry in `/etc/hosts/` file that had a name for 'localhost'.

When pointing my browser at `localhost`, the default Apache "It Works!" page did not work. However when pointing to the name I had in `/etc/hosts/` it did work.
But php file would not load and only showed "Index Of /" in the browser.

After more searching, I came to find I needed to load the mod in apache.

Trying:

```
a2query -m php7.0
No module matches php7.0
```

did not work, even though it was already installed which I discovered after trying to reinstall it

`php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)`

Finally stumbled upon [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser) in AskUbuntu and low and behold this worked for me, allowing me to enable the mod in apache

`sudo apt-get purge php*`

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0`

I don't know how or why, but it worked for me.

Comment: possibly a duplicate or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text definitely sounds like an apache/php config issue rather than anything with Drupal itself

Comment: Do you literally see the php code as plain text? If so what @LeighMason said is almost definitely the reason.

Comment: @Clive. Yes it is displayed as plain text on the web page.

Comment: You just need to tell the web server how to interpret php files in that case - Leigh provided the link for apache, if you're on nginx it'll be an fpm setup like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx

Comment: @Clive. I'm on apache2 so going to dig into that link privided.

Comment: I got the same problem for the Drupal 9 multisite setup but these two commands worked for me ,                                                                                                      
 sudo apt-get purge php* and

sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql php7.4-curl php7.4-json php7.4-cgi  php7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get the question answered:

You missed the step about setting up Apache and PHP in the [installation guide you read](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/linux-development-environments/set-up-a-local-development-drupal#environment). In particular, you have to follow the [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide from DigitalOcean - linked to in the installation guide.

Comment: Hi @hansfn. Thanks for the link. I have more issues now. Prior to following this guide, I had the basic "It Works" page working for localhost but now, it just shows `Index of /` with a file structure in place. It seems to stem from putting the ServerName section in the apache2.conf but I've removed and rebooted to see but to no avail. I will keep digging. Or install XAMPP and be done with it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: To get Drupal to run, you need to point DocumentRoot to the right directory. Anyway, you should follow the guide and do the test - "Test PHP Processing on your Web Server".

Comment: Finally got it working after completing this section of steps. Will edit my original question with what I had to do.